# Recursion counting

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to count the number of times that it runs through the recursion loop, but it keeps kicking out some crazy big numbers that are not correct. I guess the first question that I have is this even possible to do and if it is where should I put the count in the permutation method.

```
 package a02;

import java.util.Random;

public class permutations {
private static int count = 0;

static void permute(int[] a, int k) {
    if (k == a.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" [" + a[i] + "] ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
            int temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;

            permute(a, k + 1);

            temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't fix your question based on the suggestions in the answer because then the answer will no longer make any sense to future visitors who might have a similar problem.

Comment: @GhostCat Already rolled back

Comment: And, unrelated: read about java naming conventions ... class names go UpperCase always. And please: use names that have a meaning. a, k ... those names say nothing! And worse: dont reuse names: it is extremely bad practice to have a k parameter in that method, to then use *another* k as loop index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, the count++ is inside the for loop. I think that is why you are getting very large and incorrect numbers. Move the count ++ statement to either the start of your method permute or towards the end before it returns and you should have the correct output. ( In your case the count++ should be outside the whole if-else block )